# Can a Macro Uncomment itself?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Suppose I have the below, in which for every selected shape another one will be created:

```
For Each Shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange'.GroupItems
```

as you can see, at the end of the line objects within groups are commented out. Would it be possible to tell VBA to uncomment it, if for example a ListBox gives the option to apply the macro for grouped items? This would not be out of laziness, rather to save lines and possibly reduce the file size. And just to understand more how everything works. Or VBA is intrinsically blind to comments?

Comment: Reducing the code file size is a strange idea - and the file size is not affected seriously by adding some lines of code. Technically, it is possible to modify VBA code by VBA code, but it's a little bit tricky, forces a recompile (which will reset all your variables) and is often forbidden by security settings. My advice: don't go down that way.

Comment: What you wish to do is usually either done by a select case structure or by Conditional compilation.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, why is this question so wrong?

Comment: @freeflow thank you, so it is something that could be possible, however usafe as per FunThomas advice, is that correct?

Comment: It *might* be possible in some cases; in others it might not, or it might, but cause your code to misbehave. It's much simpler and more reliable to let your code decide what to do with groups.

Comment: @Bradipo NO.  You are misunderstanding again.  Neither of the two options I mention use comments.  In the first case you implement the code for both cases and then  make a choice at runtime and run the appropriate code.  In the second, you implement tthe code for both type but only compile the code for one type.  The choice is made at compile time and you lose the option to do anything other than what you compiled.

Comment: @freeflow And these scenarios would be determined by the best possible flow/speed of execution, or because something unexpected could happen with the other path the code lead to, correct?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg so in the event one chose to do so, the code would read itself as a text, rather than a set of instructions, but then it would also have to follow the instructions and hence the possible misbehaving/issues, right? I was mostly interested in this possibility of, let's call it, "self awareness" of the code. But now I understand that it could have malicious effects (which I did not consider at first) as from the first answer from FunThomas.

Comment: The code would be read as text and modified as such before being added back to a module, yes, but in the case you're describing, the code could test to see if a shape is a group and handle it accordingly. That gets you into recursion, which might hurt your brain more than having the code rewrite itself, but will work better! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of handling shapes whether within groups or not:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    For Each oSh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        Call HandleShape(oSh)
    Next
End Sub
Sub HandleShape(oSh As Shape)
    Dim x As Long
    If oSh.Type = msoGroup Then
        For x = 1 To oSh.GroupItems.Count
            Call HandleShape(oSh.GroupItems(x))
        Next
    Else
        oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```